# How to fix "Could not access network location 0" error?

Tags: windows-7, vmware

I am trying to install VMWare under Windows 7, but I get the error

> Could not access memory location 0

How can I fix this error?

Comment: @Waseem: this question is low quality, actually. 1.) it does not belong here but rather on superuser or so, 2.) address 0 means there is a null pointer access, but you give no version of the VMware you want to install nor details on the OS (e.g. x86 or x64). It's literally impossible to help you this way. Please edit your question.

Comment: You could edit your question to state what you have tried.